# How to fix inefficient cache policy on static assets with drupal website?

Tags: caching, drupal-7, assets, ttl

How to reduce the caching of static assets (image,js,css,fonts) on drupal 7 website.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TE76.png)

Answer (score 0):

CSS & JS:

1. Navigate to `/admin/config/development/performance` and enable "Aggregate and compress CSS files." and "Aggregate JavaScript files."
2. Or you can use the more advanced [AdvAgg contrib module](https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg)

Image:

1. Leverage Image Styles to reduce the dimensions of images by going here `/admin/config/media/image-styles` and setting the image field display settings to use the corresponding image style.
2. You can also navigate to `/admin/config/media/image-toolkit` and reduce the global quality of images generated by image styles
3. Or you can use the more advanced [ImageMagick contrib module](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagemagick)

Fonts:

1. Consider switching font hosting to a cloud host like Google Fonts or Adobe Fonts which are optimized